# Starting a Docker file with Docker.DotNet

Tags: docker.dotnet

Is there anyway to start a Docker container defined by a Docker file using Docker.DotNet?  I found the `BuildImageFromDockerfileAsync` method, but that seems to be expecting a stream of a tar file.  I just want to start a Docker file, or even better, a Docker compose file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker.DotNet is only a .NET wrapper for the Docker RESTful API.  It does not allow you to use Docker CLI tools programatically.